# Reading Data From PDF File And Write It Into Word File?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, ms-word

How Can We Read Data From PDF File And Write It In Word File Using Asp.net C# Code...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IFilter capabilities built into Windows, here's an article with some example code:

[Using-IFilter-in-C](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13391/Using-IFilter-in-C)

The issue with PDF files is that even if you're able to extract the plaintext of the PDF in readable form (which is *not* a guarantee by any stretch), the text will be completely unformatted. Even simple things like line breaks will be lost in many cases.

Comment: richard it works fine.if we are converting PDF to text. and as you told me it lost the style,formatting,images,graphics etc.so you have any idea about how we getting all this thing in conversion and thank you for your post..

Comment: It is not possible to recover the formatting without writing your own application to parse the PDF format directly. This would be an incredibly difficult task -- man-years of development time.

Even then, PDFs are constructed in a way that doesn't translate back into flow-based documents like Word (where text/graphics wrap lines, flow to the next page, etc.). PDF files internally don't contain much if any text flow/wrapping information, they tend to be organized around small chunks of text/graphics and their *absolute* position on the page.

For that, I recommend a third-party solution.